# Making a M2M relation required in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

My goal is to make an M2M field required in DRF serializer. Example:

```
class ModelA:
    b = ManyToManyField(B)

class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('b')
```

Here I want to make 'b' a required field for `ModelASerializer`, so that when creating an instance of A class, at least one relation is added to the newly created instance. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) with `many=True` attribute for that purpose. For example;

```
from rest_framework.serializers import PrimaryKeyRelatedField


class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=B.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('b')
```

and if you don't send `b` values then you will get required field error like;

```
{
    "b": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

also, if you want to block empty list then just use `allow_empty=False` attribute on serializer field.